# Questions regarding the colon notation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have come across the following notation in MATLAB

```
y(:, :, :, 2) = y(:, :, :, 1);


y(:, 1, :, 4) = y(:, 1, :, 3);
```

`y(:)`?

Is there a general rule on : notation.

Thanks

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and edit your question if you want to know something specific.

Answer (score 0):

All elements in that dimension. Example,

```
> A=[2, 3, 4; 0, 5, 7]
A =
   2   3   4
   0   5   7
> A(:, 2)
ans =
   3
   5
> A(1, :)
ans =
   2   3   4
```

Comment: Do you know anthing about y(:,1,:,4)?

Comment: Exactly that... Take all elemenst on first and third dimension with second and fourth dimension in 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that the actual question asked, "`y(:)`?", will give you the contents of matrix `y` reshaped to a Nx1 matrix (a.k.a. column vector).

This is a very convenient behavior because you are always guaranteed a column vector regardless of the input.

For example, given the following matrices:

```
a = [1,3;2,4];
b = [1,2,3,4];
c = [1;2;3;4];
```

`a(:)`, `b(:)`, and `c(:)` all give the following:

```
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

Comment: the example of the matrix a you give hee,, does the : notation concatenate the two columns?

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, by column. You _always_ end up with Nx1.